# hdparm spin down time not persisting between reboots

Tags: disk-management, hdparm

If enter the following commands on the command line it works as expected and spins down in the specified time.

```
sudo hdparm -S 120 /dev/sda

sudo hdparm -S 120 /dev/sdb
```

Putting this in `/etc/hdparm.conf` does nothing however. The disks just stay spun up indefinitely.

```
command_line {
    hdparm -S 120 /dev/sda
    hdparm -S 120 /dev/sdb
}
```

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04's `hdparm` version is "9.48" and if you have a look at its configuration file man page: `man hdparm.conf` you will find out that:

> Blocks beginning with the keyword 'command_line' instead of a device identifier are no longer supported for backwards compatibility by this version of hdparm.

So the correct configuration file should looks like:

```
/dev/sda {
    spindown_time = 120
}

/dev/sdb {
    spindown_time = 120
}
```

Comment: Ah! That did it. Thanks. Also I never knew there were man pages for things other than programs, Learn something new all the time.